# Azure IoT Edge setup completes successfully but does not start the edgeAgent docker image

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I'm trying to install the Azure IoT Edge runtime on a Windows 10 machine. I've followed the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart#configure-the-iot-edge-runtime) up to and including the step for calling `iotedgectl start`. When I execute the next step and run `docker ps` to verify that the `edgeAgent` container is running, I get an empty list. Has any body encountered anything like this before where the runtime says it successfully starts but nothing's running in `docker` ? I've confirmed in the IoT Hub that nothing has successfully connected for my IoT Device.

** EDIT ** : After reading some of the comments, I've found the docker logs. (Unfortunately starting with verbose logging didn't seem to help as the container appears to start normally, but it's helpful to know, so thank you @RomanKiss) The container appears to start successfully, but fails to connect to the IoT Hub via AMQP and shuts down:

`2017-12-05 22:47:10 [INF] - Edge agent attempting to connect to IoT Hub via AMQP...
2017-12-05 22:47:11 [INF] - Edge agent attempting to connect to IoT Hub via AMQP over WebSocket...`

I've verified that the connection string is correct. I'm waiting to hear back from our Operations department about investigating traffic on AMQP port 5671. The Docker container is currently running with Linux containers.

Output of `docker ps -a` :

`C:\Users\myuser\Downloads>docker ps --all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
26c1d3363ba0        microsoft/azureiotedge-agent:1.0-preview   "/usr/bin/dotnet M..."   8 seconds ago       Exited (1) 3 seconds ago                        edgeAgent`

Comment: which platform is selected in the docker? Try to switch for Linux. It looks like the edgeAgent container failed during the runtime.

Comment: one more thing, use the following command   iotedgectl --verbose DEBUG start

Comment: Could you run docker ps -a command? To know whether the Docker container was created and exit.

Comment: Added as per requests in comments

Answer (score 3):

Talking to your ops department is the best first step. We have seen similar behavior when the AMQP port (5671) is blocked. The one difference between your situation and the instances we've seen this happen is that the Edge agent will exit after about a minute instead of a few seconds.

The IoT Edge runtime (Edge Agent and Edge Hub) should fall back to AMQP over websockets if port 5671 is blocked. There is a bug preventing this at the moment and that will be fixed shortly.

In the meantime, please post the logs from the Edge Agent and we can take a look to determine if you're running into 5671 being blocked or a different issue. You can access the logs by running the command "docker logs edgeAgent".

::UPDATE:: This is one of the bugs fixed in the December update for Azure IoT Edge

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18224635)

Comment: Unfortunately this account doesn't have enough reputation to comment on the original post so adding an answer is the only option to get more information.

Comment: I'm on the fence of whether this qualifies as an answer or not.  It sort of does in that someone who appears to communicate information about the problem and what's being done, but also it sounds like something a representative would say: "We're aware of the problem and working to fix it".  If you added a link to a bug report, a temporary workaround or timeline, then this would probably survive the low quality answer filter.  Don't let this answer being deleted discourage you from posting more answers, it's just that this should be a comment, get some rep and try again later.

Comment: I'd be perfectly happy for you to delete this answer as long as you post a comment asking for the logs. That said, it looks like one person has found the answer useful already. I am a "representative". I'm on the Azure IoT Edge product team; however it's impossible for me to give a definitive answer without more information. I would have asked for that info via a comment; however I can't post comments at this time because this is a new account.